# For loop using variable as condition, Bash

Tags: bash, for-loop

I am running the following bash code:

```
num=$(ls -1 $ini/*.ini | wc -l)
echo "Running $num simulations..."
for i in {1..$num};
do
    echo "a"
done
```

And I get the following output:

```
Running 24 simulations...
a
```

It should print 24 lines of 'a', but it doesn't. What should I change? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The curly brackets don't expand variables. You could use

```
for i in $(seq $num); do
    echo "a"
done
```

See e.g. `man bash`:

> [...]
>
> A sequence expression takes the form `{x..y[..incr]}`, where `x` and  `y`  are  either
>   integers  or  single characters, and incr, an optional increment, is an integer.
>   When integers are supplied, the expression expands to each number between `x`  and
>   `y`,  inclusive.
>
> [...]
>
> Brace  expansion  is  performed  before any other expansions, and any characters
>   special to other expansions are preserved in the result.  It  is  strictly  textual. 
>   Bash  does  not apply any syntactic interpretation to the context of the
>   expansion or the text between the braces.
>
> [...]

Comment: Note to OS X users: the optional-increment feature is NOT available as of OS X 10.8.2, which comes with bash 3.2.48.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for (( i=0; i < $num; i++ ))
do
    echo "a"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The brace expansion only works for literals, it does not expand variables.

Possible workaround:

```
for i in $(seq 1 $num) ; do
```

Answer (score 0):

Read:

- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29
- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.7B1...24n.7D

Disregard answers involving `seq(1)`. [cdarke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13048894/495451) demonstrates correct iteration.

Also note that this is a bash-specific issue. Other shells with brace expansion will evaluate parameter expansions first, but there are tradeoffs.

Comment: Please don't JUST tell us WHAT not to do, but also WHY NOT. Why not use `seq`? Performance? Tradeoffs (convenience vs. speed)?

Comment: @mklement Word-splitting command substitution output is a bad idea, and any `for x in $(anything)` pattern is problematic. Using `seq` for iteration is pointless because there are built-in ways to do this that are faster, shorter, and portable. `seq` is a non-standard command. Not understanding this principle is also what led to the much worse mistake of the questioner using `$(ls)`. I would rather not reiterate the same FAQs on basic usage for almost every answer to questions tagged with bash. Maybe it's not as bad elsewhere on S/O.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying; good to know that `seq` is non-standard. Yes, using `(( ... ))` is faster and the better choice, but it's clearly not _shorter_. There is nothing wrong with the OP's use of `$(ls ... | wc -l)` - it always returns only a _single, white-space-free_ token, so there's no danger of undesirable word-splitting (there IS unwanted leading whitespace in the result, but that's a separate issue). Generally, `for x in $(...)` is _potentially_ problematic, but it definitely has its uses: all that is needed for proper line-by-line processing is to set `$IFS` to `$'\n'` (temporarily).

Comment: @mklement There are a number of shorter constructs. `while ((n++<num))` and `for((n=0;++n<num;))do` to name a few. As for `$(ls)`, it's *always* incorrect. There are other issues aside from whitespace, the most important being globbing (and files that contain glob characters). Filenames may contain newlines. `ls` isn't for use in scripts. Use globs directly. Always quote expansions. There are some limited use cases for word-splitting in POSIX sh where in the absence of arrays then best you can do is wordsplit and prey. In Bash, and ksh-like shells, there are no significant remaining uses.

Comment: Using `while ((n++<num))` without explicit initialization of `n` is asking for trouble. `for((n=0;++n<num;))do` hampers readability. Agreed: for _enumeration of files matching a name pattern_, globbing is absolutely the way to go, for all the reasons you state. By contrast, the OP used `ls -1` in a command substitution to _count_ matching files: works fine, even with filenames with embedded newlines. I'm genuinely curious: how would you count matching files (other than using a counter in a globbing loop)? I eventually followed the links in your answer - instructive, in-depth stuff; thanks.

Comment: I was wrong about the following: "all that is needed for proper line-by-line processing is to set $IFS to $'\n' (temporarily)." As you state, accidental globbing can result. Thus, methinks, the _safe way to loop over output from a command line by line_ is to use the following (taken from the site you linked to): `while IFS='' read -r line; do ...; done <<<"$(...)"`. So, agreed: best to stay away from `for x in $(...)`, unless you're absolutely sure that no unwanted expansions can occur in the command's output (which just happens to be the case with `$(seq $num)`).

Comment: @mklement Yes it is usually good to initialize variables used in arithmetic. For `while`, `n` has to be set beforehand. I usually declare locals to initialize. `ls -1` is another non-standard option that you shouldn't have to use. `files=(*); num=${#files[@]}`. I suppose it won't kill you to use `seq` if you like it for some reason, just keep it out of real code. Yes that's a good while loop. `mapfile` is another option. Usually you would redirect from a process substitution or use a pipe instead of `<<<"$()"`, which generates the entire output and dumps it to a temporary file before starting.

Comment: SO is gently admonishing to avoid extended discussions - time to stop. Thanks for your input, I learned a few things. Final thoughts: If you wanted to control whether or not to include _hidden_ files in counting, you could use `num=$(shopt -s dotglob; files=(*); echo "${#files[@]}")`. I was wrong about another thing: `ls | wc -l` (whether with the `-1` option or not) does NOT work properly with file names with embedded newlines - in practice, though, I doubt that many people have to plan for this scenario. Finder on OS X prevents interactive renaming of files to strings with embedded newlines.

Comment: All right, one for the road: `files=(*); num=${#files[@]}` returns *1* rather than 0, if there is NO match at all (if the `nullglob` shell option is off, which it is by default). To guard against that, use `num=$(shopt -s nullglob; files=(*); printf ${#files[@]})` (and simply add the `dotglob` option, as needed).

Comment: @mklement Yes enabling nullglob is a good idea. It is used much more frequently than dotglob in fact. Unfortunately every shell that has a null globbing feature does it differently, and obviously most shells don't have it at all. In those cases you have to test that the result is actually a file. Another fun solution is `echo $(($(find . -maxdepth 1 -printf 1+)0))`. There are many possible answers.